# Windows Forms C# Dynamic controls problem

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, combobox, controls

I'm trying to make a form where the user can add group boxes with other controls inside.
groupboxes and other controls are all created dynamically.

[Program image. *the button "Adicionar Pergunta" adds a new group box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79l1t.png)

Inside the groupbox is a combobox where the user can choose the preset of controls inside the groupbox.
each preset have different controls or controls in different locations of the group box.
my problem is that when the user change the preset of one groupbox all the other combobox stop working.

Here is the my script:

Variables:

```
int groupboxcount = 2;
    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
    TextBox tx1 = new TextBox();
    TextBox tx2 = new TextBox();

    GroupBox gb;
    ComboBox cb;
    RadioButton rb_1;
    RadioButton rb_2;
    RadioButton rb_V;
    RadioButton rb_F;
    TextBox tx_1;
    TextBox tx_2;
```

Button Click:

```
{
        gb = new GroupBox();
        NumericUpDown Nud1 = new NumericUpDown();



        cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(cb2_selectec_index_changed);
        RichTextBox RichTextBox2 = new RichTextBox();
        Label labelA1 = new Label();
        Label labelA2 = new Label();
        Label labelA3 = new Label();

        gb.Name = "groupBox" + groupboxcount;
        gb.Text = "Pergunta ";
        gb.Height = 182;
        gb.Width = 520;
        gb.Location = new Point(groupBox1.Location.X, gb.Location.Y + gb.Height + 125);


        Nud1.Height = 20;
        Nud1.Width = 41;
        Nud1.Location = new Point(6, 37);
        Nud1.Value = groupboxcount;

        cb.Items.Add("Enunciado");
        cb.Items.Add("Pergunta normal");
        cb.Items.Add("Escolha multipla");
        cb.Items.Add("Verdadeiro/Falso");
        cb.Height = 21;
        cb.Width = 121;
        cb.Location = new Point(53, 36);
        RichTextBox2.Height = 80;
        RichTextBox2.Width = 249;
        RichTextBox2.Location = new Point(211, 37);
        labelA1.Text = "Nº";
        labelA2.Text = "Tipo de pergunta";
        labelA3.Text = "Pergunta";
        labelA1.Location = new Point(6, 19);
        labelA2.Location = new Point(59, 19);
        labelA3.Location = new Point(208, 19);
        labelA1.Width = 20;

        this.Controls.Add(gb);
        gb.Controls.Add(Nud1);
        gb.Controls.Add(cb);
        gb.Controls.Add(RichTextBox2);
        gb.Controls.Add(labelA1);
        gb.Controls.Add(labelA2);
        gb.Controls.Add(labelA3);


        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, gb.Location.Y + button1.Height + 200);

        groupboxcount++;
    }
```

Combobox cb2 selected index changed:

```
{
        if (cb.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            //Apenas mostra enunciado
        }
        if (cb.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            //recebe resposta
        }


        if (cb.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            rb_1 = new RadioButton();
            rb_2 = new RadioButton();
            tx_1 = new TextBox();
            tx_2 = new TextBox();

            rb_1.Text = "opção 1";
            rb_1.Location = new Point(120, 75);
            rb_2.Text = "opção 2";
            rb_2.Location = new Point(120, 100);
            tx_2.Location = new Point(5, 100);
            tx_1.Location = new Point(5, 75);


            this.gb.Controls.Add(rb_1);
            this.gb.Controls.Add(rb_2);
            this.gb.Controls.Add(tx_1);
            this.gb.Controls.Add(tx_2);
        }
        else
        {
            this.gb.Controls.Remove(rb_1);
            this.gb.Controls.Remove(rb_2);
            this.gb.Controls.Remove(tx_1);
            this.gb.Controls.Remove(tx_2);
        }

        if (cb.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            rb_V = new RadioButton();
            rb_F = new RadioButton();

            rb_V.Text = "Verdadeiro";
            rb_V.Location = new Point(120, 75);
            rb_F.Text = "Falso";
            rb_F.Location = new Point(120, 100);

            this.gb.Controls.Add(rb_V);
            this.gb.Controls.Add(rb_F);

        }
        else
        {
            this.gb.Controls.Remove(rb_V);
            this.gb.Controls.Remove(rb_F);
        }
    }
```

I would appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Help you *what*?  What is the issue here?

Comment: my problem is that when the user change the preset of one groupbox all the other combobox stop working.

Comment: You might want to look into `UserControl`s - they are all comprised of the same controls, so just make one new thing.  Otherwise seems like a job for **[the AWESOME Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)**

Comment: ok im trying that thanks